# Unable to Access Salesforce Rest Web Service

Tags: web-services, rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce, authorization

We have REST based web services hosted on Salesforce.com. We are able to access the web services by using workbench REST explorer but we can't access the web service directly in browser and getting error "INVALID_SESSION_ID". Please provide any pointers to access this service directly in browser. We have Saleforce user id , password and Security Token. We are passing security token in the header to access the service directly in the browser but getting "INVALID_SESSION_ID".

-H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX" where XXXXXXXXX is the security token.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Parveen

Comment: You can use with this applicationc 
hrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm/HttpClient.html

Comment: We can't install this extension due to some issues. Can you please suggest some other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to use oauth Access token in the header rather than security token. So create a app on salesforce and enable oauth on that app. Now you need to get access token for your salesforce account. After that pass this access token in the header (like you are passing security token).

This will work as i have used this.

Comment: Can you please confirm how to get the access token? Please share an example of how to specify access token in the header?